# How to come out of root user?

Tags: sudo, root, logout

I just gained root access following steps from the http://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Ubuntu. My prompt get changed from `$` to `#` sign, indicating I have root access. Now I have come out or log out or disable root access. For that I tried 
`sudo passwd -dl root`. Then it shows the message:

```
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

But I still have root access, and I am still having `#` sign instead of `$`.

`root@hostname:~#` still appears instead of `xyz@hostname:~$`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

From what I gather you're simply trying to return to your user account after gaining access to root.

Try typing

```
exit
```

in terminal. Or you can simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: This just closed the whole ssh client.

Comment: CTRL-D did it for me from root@ to linux shell.  The good old 'exit' was not recognized or 'quit' did not work either.

Answer (score 17):

Just type `exit` and you will leave the root shell and get a shell of your previous user.