# How to switch user in terminal

Tags: command-line, su

I am currently:

```
root@sensu-server-client:/#
```

I wish to change to:

```
sensu@sensu-server-client:/#
```

How does one do this. I tried: `su sensu` but nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://askubuntu.com/a/489937/119531

Comment: @Raphael Not possible duplicate. I logged in as root, Exit will not work as I will log out of the server. Think.

Comment: `su - sensu` should work. However try also `sudo -iu sensu`

Comment: What's the output of `getent passwd sensu`?

Answer (score 21):

You should use `su`:

```
su [-|-l|--login] USERNAME
```

If you specify the login option (either `-`, or `-l`, or `--login`: all are synonyms), you will get an environment similar to if you directly logged in as that user. Otherwise you stay in the current environment (e.g. many `env` variables, the current directory, etc).

Example: (note the usernames and current working directories!)

```
root@wolf-pack:~# su bytecommander
bytecommander@wolf-pack:/root$ exit
exit

root@wolf-pack:~# su - bytecommander
bytecommander@wolf-pack:~$ exit
logout

root@wolf-pack:~#
```

PS: If you run `su` not as root, you will of course be prompted for the password of the user as who you want to log in.